# Отмена стандартного Anchor Scroll

Tags: javascript

У меня есть табы, сделанные на jq. при выборе таба, к путь сайта, добавляется /#tab-number..., и страница скролится к выбранному табу. добавляется это для того, чтобы клиент мог дать ссылку кому-то на определенный таб и он открылся при переходе по ссылке. Но клиента не устраивает, что при выборе таба, страница куда-то едет... Подскажите, как отменить стандартный скролл?

```js
$('body').on("click","a.dropdown-item", function (event) {
  if($(this).attr('href')!=null)
  {
            event.preventDefault();
            hreff=$(this).data('href').substr(1);
            location.hash = hreff;
  }
 });
```

Comment: Поможем только в случае если покажите код JS где устанавливается якорь /#tab-number

Comment: http://www.agro.5.demo0.ru/sertif%D1%96kati/#list-110-141

Comment: Зачем нам ваша ссылка ? ))

JS код !== ссылка на сайт ))

Comment: $('body').on("click","a.dropdown-item", function (event) {
  if($(this).attr('href')!=null)
  {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        hreff=$(this).data('href').substr(1);
                        location.hash = hreff;
  }
 });

Answer (score 1):

Думаю проблема в неправильности вашего кода, поправил:

```js
$('body').on("click","a.dropdown-item", function (event) {
  if($(this).attr('data-href')!=null)
  {
            event.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('data-href').split('#')[1];
            location.hash = href;
            console.log(href);
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" style="display: block;">
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-141" role="tab-sub">Селітра аміачна</a>
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-144" role="tab-sub">Вапнякова селітра</a>
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-140" role="tab-sub">Аміак водний техн.</a>
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-139" role="tab-sub">Безводний аміак</a>
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-138" role="tab-sub">Сульфат амонію кристал</a>
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-137" role="tab-sub">Сульфат амонію гранул</a>
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-136" role="tab-sub">Карбамід</a>
<a class="dropdown-item list-group-item" href="" data-href="#list-110-135" role="tab-sub">КАС</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Зайдите на сайт,наведите курсор на категорию и покликайте по выпадающим меню. Увидите, как сайт едет вниз, к заголовку категории. это происходит потому, что в путь вписывается хэш. Суть вопроса была в том, как отменить вот это самое подъезжание страницы к заголовку. Убрать хеш не могу, поскольку его читает jq  и открывает нужную вкладку, вслучае если человек пришел по прамой ссылке.

Comment: ну в свём коде при смене хеша поставьте  setTimeout(function() {

    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 1);  в параметр scrollTo поставьте значение в px через сколько пикселй ваш меню от top

Comment: Все равно вижно как страница прыгает... Проблему решил.. Все оказалось очень просто. нужно было добавить return false. и она перестала ездить))